# How to parse a string list query param in DRF serializers?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, query-string

I'm building a REST API to handle user requests in the following form:

```
localhost:8000/search/?categories=<category1>,<category2>&parts=<id1>,<id2>
```

Where `,` is supposed to be the delimiter for the parser.

My view processes the request and passes the query params to the serializer, but I just cannot get the raw strings parsed to a list of strings.

My attempt so far:

```
class StringListField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField()

class LookupPartsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    categories = StringListField()
    parts = StringListField()

class LookupParts(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = LookupPartsSerializer(data=request.query_params)
        serializer.is_valid()
        return Response(serializer.validated_data)
```

My desired output is like:

```
{
    "categories": [
        "<category1>",
        "<category2>"
    ],
    "parts": [
        "<id1>",
        "<id2>"
    ]
}
```

But now I'm getting:

```
{
    "categories": [
        "<category1>,<category2>"
    ],
    "parts": [
        "<id1>,<id2>"
    ]
}
```

So basically I'm looking for an option to pass a delimiter argument to the `StringListField` or add some custom parsing method.

#### NOTE:

I'm aware, that if I change the query pattern from `?categories=<category1>,<category2>...` to `?categories=<category1>&categories=<category2>...` then I'd get the desired results, but I'd like to stick to my original approach.

Comment: Any particular reason for using serializers? This looks like an anti-pattern to me, and I doubt is_valid() is returning true in this case

Comment: Serializer is needed for validation and parsing. Actually it does return `True`, go ahead and try. What pattern would you suggest by the way?

Comment: I'm getting False when I try it locally. I can still suggest how to make this work though: try overriding the to_representation() method of the StringListField

Comment: I definitely get a `True` here :) Yeah I was considering that one, but hoped for a general best practice for a common problem like this.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to implement a customer `to_representation()`:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(StringListField, self).to_representation(instance)

    data['parts'] = data['parts'].split(',') if isinstance(data['parts'], str) else data['parts']
    data['categories'] = data['categories'].split(',') if isinstance(data['categories'], str) else data['categories']

    return data
```

Hope it helps!